# Git clone from private network to remote through vpn ssh

Tags: ssh, vpn, git

I work on a private network with a git repository hosted there at git.mycompany.com.

I have a remote server without access to this private network, I access it via ssh. To get my code to the server, I was recommended to use scp. This isn't ideal.

I am trying to use ssh forwarding to allow me to use commands like git clone on this server like

`ssh -L 9418:git.mycompany.com:9418 my.name@1.2.3.4`

Then use git clone like

`git clone my.name@localhost:my_project/my_project.git`

after creating and adding an ssh key to my git server as I usually would. But git asks me for a password, and entering my password does not work, so I assume something in my method is incorrect.

`Permission denied, please try again.`

I can't tell if the authorization is not working, or my traffic forwarding is wrong.

Comment: Why do you forward port 9418? With the syntax you showed, git uses SSH, on port 22.

Answer (score 1):

If you have ssh already working, you can simply clone through it with:

```
git clone ssh://server/path/to/repository.git
```

There is no need to manually set up a ssh tunnel. The reverse can be done with a push. Create an empty repository on the remote server:

```
cd /path/
git init --bare remote.git
```

then push to it from your repository:

```
git push ssh://server/path/remote.git
```